# Cannot read property of undefined - Multiarray

Tags: jquery, arrays, ajax, xml

I'm trying to load a xml file and save some information into an array. But i always get the error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property "0" of undefined.
Thanks for help in advance.

```
var myArray = [[]]
jQuery.ajax({
    url: '../xml/someXml.xml',
    type:'GET',
    dataType: 'xml',
    success: function(data) {
        // Extract relevant data from XML
        var xml = $.parseXML(data);
        var $xml = $(xml);
        var $piece = $xml.find("piece");
        $piece.each(function() {
            var t = [];
            var attr1 = $(this).find("attr1").text();
            var attr2 = $(this).find("attr2").text();
            var attr3 = $(this).find("attr3").text();
            t.push(attr1);
            t.push(attr2);
            t.push(attr3);
            myArray.push(t);
        })
    }
});
alert(myArray[0][0]);
```

Comment: You know what `async` means? That will not work ...

Comment: Please state the real exception you get, I doubt "xy" is the real property name of the example.

Comment: Obviously I do not understand what async means, otherwise I wouldn't program the stuff?!

Comment: Include the line number the error references.  Regardless @BenjaminPeter is correct that `myArray` will not be populated when you try to reference it.

Answer (score 1):

*eisbehr* might be right that this could be a problem related to asynchronicity of Ajax (see [wikipedia ajax](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_(programming))). You cannot assume any order between the execution time of the success method and the time your jquery.ajax function call returns. This all your actions that depend on the data of the ajax call must initiate in the success callback function.

Usually ajax is used to retrieve remote documents or data from the webserver which might take some time. Asynchronicity is a way to allow the browser and script to continue processing while waiting for the requested data.

Try moving your `alert(myArray[0][0]);` statement into the success callback function and see what happens.

If this does not work there might be another problem with the data parsing, you could use the browser's javascript debugger to see if you get the expected results in the success callback function. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Debugger/How_to/Set_a_breakpoint for help on that.